# Jupyter notebook within vs code not showing output type like list or dict, but can showing number, string?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook within vs code  not showing output type like list or dict, but can showing number, string. Does anyone know why? And how I can fix this?

I tried for a long time, but couldn't find the cause of the problem?

[image]

Hope to get help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This resolves after changing the jupyter notebook output renderer to 'text'. Please see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75859832/cannot-print-a-number-list/75924158#75924158) for the details.