# Cannot print a number list

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook .ipynb files in Visual Studio Code. When I try to run the command [1,2,3,4], nothing appears in the notebook's interactive output window. I have attached an image of the issue. Additionally, when I try to print a NumPy array that contains numeric values, it does not display commas between the elements. [image: Here is a screenshot of the issue]

Steps to reproduce the issue in the screenshot:

1. Launch the VS code from the Anaconda Environment.
2. Open any Jupyter notebook file (with .ipynb extension) or create one.
3. Open the file and run the code below:

   [1,2,3,4]

[This is I am getting as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D175.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem shown in your screenshot. Please add more details to reproduce the issue, and add acode-block showing how to reproduce your NumPy issue (a [mre]).

Comment: Hi , I added the steps to reproduce this issue. I discovered another stackeoverflow question regading the same issue. But, nobody addressed that question yet, not mine either. I posted the link of that post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74860859/jupyter-notebook-within-vs-code-not-showing-output-type-like-list-or-dict-but-c) @user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the output menu on the left and choosing a different presentation. That looks like a custom renderer and it likely doesn't handle that output format correctly
[image]

Comment: Thank you @aaron. It worked. I was viewing in the data table renderer mode. I changed it to vs code built-in notebook output renderer.